# nodejs can't receive on private channel of socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am initiating socket.io between nodejs (express), and front end. Basically, from nodejs, I am emitting a broadcast to private channel. Then, I want to receive the call back of this broadcast, on the same channel as well.

This is the setup in server.js:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);


const api = require('../api/AuthController')


var server = http.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('server is running on port', server.address().port);
});

const routes = require('../api/routes');
routes(app,io);

//socket config
global.io = io; //added
```

Then in AuthController, I am using global.io to emit, and receive in private channel:

```
global.io.emit(`news${user._id}`, { hello: 'new request');
                        global.io.on('conection', function (socket) {
                            socket.on(`news${user._id}`, function (message) {
                                console.log('from console', message.value);
                            });
                        });
```

I am able to emit perfectly fine to frontend, but I am not able to receive anything when the front end emits back on the same channel.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks,

**Edit**

FrontEnd Code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:adhara_socket_io/adhara_socket_io.dart';
import 'package:geocoder/geocoder.dart';

const String URI = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/";

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  _MyHomePageState();

  List<String> toPrint = ["trying to connect"];
  SocketIOManager manager;
  Map<String, SocketIO> sockets = {};
  Map<String, bool> _isProbablyConnected = {};
  bool newtripRequest = false;
  var pickupController;
  var dropoffController;
  SocketIO socketController;
  var driver = 'driver';
  String socketIdentifier;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    manager = SocketIOManager();
    initSocket("default");

  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }




  initSocket(String identifier) async {
    setState(() => _isProbablyConnected[identifier] = true);
    SocketIO socket = await manager.createInstance(SocketOptions(
        //Socket IO server URI
        URI,
        nameSpace: (identifier == "namespaced") ? "/adhara" : "/",
        //Query params - can be used for authentication
        query: {
          "auth": "--SOME AUTH STRING---",
          "info": "new connection from adhara-socketio",
          "timestamp": DateTime.now().toString()
        },
        //Enable or disable platform channel logging
        enableLogging: false,
        transports: [
          Transports.WEB_SOCKET /*, Transports.POLLING*/
        ] //Enable required transport
        ));
    setState(() {
      socketIdentifier = identifier;
    });
    socket.onConnect((data) {
      pprint("connected...");
      pprint(data);
      sendMessage('news', 'yes', socketIdentifier);
    });

    socket.onConnectError(pprint);
    socket.onConnectTimeout(pprint);
    socket.onError(pprint);
    socket.onDisconnect(pprint);
    socket.on("news", (data) => newTripRquest(data));
    socket.connect();
    sockets[identifier] = socket;
  }

  bool isProbablyConnected(String identifier) {
    return _isProbablyConnected[identifier] ?? false;
  }

  disconnect(String identifier) async {
    await manager.clearInstance(sockets[identifier]);
    setState(() => _isProbablyConnected[identifier] = false);
  }

  sendMessage(privateChannel, messageBody, identifier) {
    //pprint("sending message from '$identifier'...");
    sockets[identifier].emit(driverChannel, [
      {'response' : messageBody}]);
    //pprint("Message emitted from '$identifier'...");
  }

  pprint(data) {
    setState(() {
      if (data is Map) {
        data = json.encode(data);
      }
      print(data);
      toPrint.add(data);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Could you share your frontend code?

Comment: sure...updated in the question

Comment: Are you sure the frontend sends the message to the same channel the server listening on? (`news${user._id}`)

Comment: yes....If I try to listen to the same function from server.js, I am able to receive the emitted message:

io.on('connection', function(socket){
        socket.on(`news_ID_ashardcoded`, function (message) {
        console.log('from console', message.value);
         });
    });

but, when I try to create an instance with 'global.io' @ auth.controller, I am not receiving anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a typo ('conection'), and there's no closing brace in the emit's object.

Here's the fixed version of your AuthController's code:

```
global.io.emit(`news${user._id}`, { hello: 'new request' });

global.io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on(`news${user._id}`, function (message) {
    console.log('from console', message.value);
  });
});
```

I hope it helps!